# (400) Bad Request when transferring large files

Tags: c#, wcf

I have the same problem when trying to transfer files larger than 50kb the error message is "(400) Bad Request"

Can someone tell me where I'm wrong?

The following code below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
  <system.serviceModel> 


    <bindings> 
      <basicHttpBinding> 
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer" closeTimeout="00:10:00" 
          openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
          messageEncoding="Text"  transferMode="Buffered" 
          useDefaultWebProxy="true"> 
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" /> 
          <security mode="None"> 
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" 
              realm="" /> 
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" /> 
          </security> 
        </binding> 
      </basicHttpBinding> 
    </bindings> 
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" /> 
    <client> 

      <endpoint  address="http://localhost:57728/FileTransfer.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer" contract="WCFFileTransfer.IFileTransfer" 
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer" /> 

    </client> 


  </system.serviceModel> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Turn WCF tracing on (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx). This really helps.

Comment: +1 For WCF tracing.  Also, what does your server config look like?

Comment: What you have shown in your question is the client configuration. The error is coming from the server. You need to make the same changes to the web.config on the server side.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not really a useful title for a question. Please try to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the web.config on the server has the following setting:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
    ....
</system.web>
```